# How high can a player go?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In *Minecraft*, you can only build up to a certain height limit (which is something around 256). However, if a player uses mods/hacks to go above the limit (Or simply goes into Creative Mode), then they can go above the height limit.

How high is the player height limit in *Minecraft*? Is there even a limit to it? I've tried testing this myself, but my thumb started hurting when I reached Y= 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no limit to a player's height. The Y coordinate is tracked with the same size of variable as the X and Z, so you can go as infinitely* high as you can travel infinitely* far. There is no extra limitation placed on player height, so the only limitation is *how* to get there.

With cheats on, you can use `/tp` to experiment with how high you can go, and you can see your position by toggling on the debug screen with <kbd>F3</kbd>.

<sub>* Not actually infinite, but it takes many days of real time to walk that far.</sub>

Answer (score 22):

The answer to your question can easily be found on the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Altitude).

> **The maximum height (coordinates) a player can reach is displayed as "6.7108E7" (6.7E7 is 6.7 times 10^7th, or 67 million, approximately
> 2^26th)**

Answer (score 4):

You can reach 1 quadrillion blocks. After that you will get kicked with the message "Illegal Stance".

Answer (score 0):

The highest you can go is 2,147,483,646. I tried it out and it won't register the height above this. If you do keep going though you do get kicked and can never join your world again.

Comment: Never? Presumably you could play on it again after you manually edit or delete the player.dat file so the game no longer reads an impossible data value when it tries to read your position.

Comment: Thing is, is there also any kind of source that can validate this number?